# How to keep input field value when using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, devise

When using devise to manage user registration/login process, when input fields failed validation, page is refreshed and all inputs fields become blank. How could I keep the input fields value so user don't have to fill them again?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are using `redirect_to` instead of `render` on error, maybe?  what's the code look like in your controller OR are you using their default code?

Comment: I checked devise source code, it seems like it use respond_with resouce, which I reckon is render,not redirect. is the input value not saved in cookie or session?